# Visual phototransduction, neurons depolarization when no light: why?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, vision, human-eye

While reading into [visual phototransduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_phototransduction) I was surprised to learn that photoreceptor cells are actually *depolarized* when there is *NO* excitation (no light, i.e. when you see nothing, black) and *hyperpolarized* when there is light (I expected the opposite).

This got me thinking...

Let the collection of neurons located *within* the eye be referred-to as **IEN** (inside-eye neurons) and, similarly, the collection of neurons *directly linked to the eye*, yet *external to it* be referred-to as **OEN** (outside-eye neurons).

Let the collection of neurons *directly getting input from the retina* be referred-to as **RN** (retinal neurons). I'm assuming **RN < IEN** (subset of -
 correct me if I'm meaningfully-wrong).

And finally, let the collection of neurons that *directly link to **OENs*** but are part of ***IEN*** be referred-to as **XN** (eXporter-neurons, in the sense that they export visual information from the eye to the "listeners" outside of it).

So the path of visual stimulus would then be **RN -> [...] -> XN -> OEN**.

Now, if my eyes were to be completely popped-out I'm assuming that relative to **OENs** that would have the same effect as **XNs** not passing along any excitatory/inhibitory information at all. Also, since what I'd perceive would be pure black, that seems to imply that **XNs** also don't get activated at all when we *actually see* black (e.g. close our eyes in a very dark room).

So, when we perceive black => **RNs** get *depolarized* => they [release glutamate continuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoreceptor_cell#Phototransduction) => **XNs** don't excite/inhibit **OENs** at all (seems to also imply that **RNs** don't intersect **XNs**). It is this inversion that intrigues me - why is it that for **XNs** to transmit *NO* information **RNs** have to continuously be excited? By that sense, this makes me think of the eye as if it was a big **NOT gate**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**
The reason for the depolarized state of photoreceptors in the dark is unknown as far as I know. It probably has its roots deep in the evolution of the eye.

**Background**
Indeed, photoreceptors are continuously active in the dark. A steady current flows through open channels (mainly Na+ ions). This current is called the dark current and it partially depolarizes the photoreceptor cell. The depolarized photoreceptor releases neurotransmitter (glutamate) to secondary neurons. Upon illumination of the photoreceptors rhodopsin molecules are isomerized to the active form and the photoreceptor cascade (Fig. 1) is initiated. This ultimately closes the cation channels in the photoreceptor's membrane, stopping the dark current.  This leads to cell membrane hyperpolarization and inhibition of glutamate release to the second-order neuron (Fig. 1).

Admittedly, I do not know *why* phototransduction exactly is organized this way. There is a lot known about the evolutin of phototransduction (*e.g.*, [Lamb *et al*., 2016)](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/33/8/2064/2579344), but *why* the dark current exists is unknown as far as I know. I surmise it is probably an evolutionary relic. Evolution eventually has to work with pre-exisiting features to generate new structures, or alter them. Simple photosensitive spots evolved into the complex eyes observed in today's vertebrates. Evolution thereby used what was there and that happened to be an energetically unfavorable 'NOT' gate.

[image: Phototransduction]
Fig. 1. Phototransduction in photoreceptors. source: [Kolb, (2012)](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-ii-anatomy-and-physiology-of-the-retina/photoreceptors/)

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Kolb, Webvision. The Organization of the Retina and Visual System (2012)](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-ii-anatomy-and-physiology-of-the-retina/photoreceptors/)

**-** [Lamb *et al*., *Molec Biol Evol* (2016); **33**(8): 2064–87](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/33/8/2064/2579344)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. As I was reading it, another possible explanation struck me that might make the NOT gate behaviour actually energetically favourable: with a NOT gate it's always _one or the other_ (primary/secondary neurons) consuming energy - the alternative would make both consume energy at the same time when there's light. So maybe a NOT gate makes it possible overall to consume less energy.

Comment: And yet another idea: even if the _overall_ energy consumption is slightly larger with the NOT gate behaviour, there might actually be another trick evolution has played - energy consumption is still smaller in the case when _there is_ light - but unlike darkness, light also means substantial visual content to process. In short, it might matter more to consume _less_ energy in _light_ (to "redirect" the rest to the secondary neurons processing the visual content) than consuming _none_ in _darkness_.